# What is the CidrIp in Security groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-security-group

I am creating a self ingress rule in a security group. I have created a CloudFormation template for the security groups, but I couldn't understand what is the `CidrIp` that I need to give here:

```
"SelfIngress1": [
          {
            "IpProtocol" : "tcp",
            "FromPort"   : "7600",
            "ToPort"     : "7600",
            "CidrIp"     : "10.0.0.0/1"
          },
```

What is the `CidrIp` that I have to provide here? Do I have to get it from the subnet where the VPC associates?

Answer (score 14):

From [AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ec2-security-group-ingress.html#cfn-ec2-security-group-ingress-cidrip):

> CidrIp
>
> An IPv4 CIDR range.
>
> For an overview of CIDR ranges, go to the [Wikipedia Tutorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing).

That field defines the IP address range (in CIDR notation) that is permitted to send inbound traffic through the security group.

Your security group is permitting inbound traffic on port `7200`, but it also needs an IP address range, such as:

- `0.0.0.0/0` means from the whole Internet
- `11.22.33.44/32` means only from `11.22.33.44`
- `10.5.2.0/24` means only from `10.5.2.x` (with anything as the last number)